# Why equal sign wasn't used for boundaries for radius ($r < b$) between internal and external conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, conductors, boundary-conditions

Why boundaries for radius between internal and external conductor are set to
$a \leq r < b$ instead of $a \leq r \leq b$?
Example: An air coaxial line made of copper ($μ \sim μ_0$) is given. A constant current I flows through the inner conductor. The radius of the inner conductor is a and the outer conductor is of negligible thickness of radius b.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In other book boundaries are defined like this
[image]

Comment: Equal sign was used both for r <= a and r >= a because when a is replaced in equations with r they will both be same

Comment: Is it more correct to replace a <= r < b with a <= r <= b and r >= b with r > b?

Comment: I've removed my comments since I wasn't really happy with my answer. I'm not a Physicist by trade - I'm a Mathematician - so just in case there is some Physical reason - ignore what I said for now

Comment: if B(b)=0 (why?) than only r<=a<b makes sense .

Comment: In other book boundaries were defined as a <= r <= b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $r=a$ the function is continuous, so there is no ambiguity.  At $r=b$ the function is discontinuous, so you have to be more careful.  If it were $\leq$ on both sides you would have two different answers for $r=b$

**Edit after Comment**

I think you can argue that it should be $r<b$ and $r>b$ since $r=b$ is a singularity and the value is therefore undefined. I like that version the best, but a physicist would pick one of the other versions because our brains are wired to think that there must be an answer *at* $r=b$.  Ask on the math Stackexchange forum.

Of course, all of this is like arguing over how many angels can dance on a pin. The abrupt discontinuity is an idealization that cannot occur in nature.

Comment: So is it more correct to set a <= r <= b and r > b?

Comment: I don't think it matters.  Either way you would take the limit as $r\rightarrow b$ from the left and from the right.  You can assign $r=b$ (a set of measure zero) to either one.  Your way seems better if you first think of approaching from the left.  The original way seems better if you are approaching from the right.  I think you can argue that it should be $r<b$ and $r>b$ since $r=b$ is a singularity and the value is therefore undefined.  Thinking about it now, I think that that is the best way to write it. I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much